# SSIS Package Permission Issue on TFS

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, tfs, permissions, ssis

I am a newbie to SSIS. I am using SQL Server 2008R2. I have created SSIS Package. I deployed that package on TFS by manually placing the package in my local folder(Mapped with TFS). And after placing the package, I checked out the pending changes.(Committed)

But when I tried to run the SSIS package from TFS Server's mapped folder (C:\TFS\SSIS\ for example) from my local machine, it gave me an error message that you do not have required permission. Same happens with other users who Checkout my SSIS package on their local machine. See the image below. But when Build my package and run from my project directory, it gives no error and runs smoothly.

Why it is happening? 
Thanks in Advance [image]
NOTE: I am deploying my package using "File System".

Comment: It usually happens when I add Configuration file.

Comment: are you sure the file is not Read Only?

Comment: Yes! I am sure. I think it seems to be an issue of TFS. Package runs fine before placing on TFS. But after checking out same package from TFS, it gives me that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Server Workspaces (the default in TFS 2010 and earlier) instead of Local Workspaces, TFS will automatically mark the file as read-only which would cause this error.  As soon as you check it into TFS it marks it as read-only.

If this is the cause you can check it out of TFS, which will turn read-only off, manually turn read-only off (not recommended), or if you're using TFS 2012 use a Local Workspace (recommended option).

Here's how you set your Workspace to ensure it's setup as a Local workspace (no more messing with read-only flags).

[image]

Comment: How can I change Read-Only property?

Comment: Right-click file in windows explorer, go to properties, an uncheck the read-only setting.

Comment: Right! Before executing "Check out pending changes..." or after checking in? I have unchecked "Read-Only" property. Will it take effect as TFS is not detecting any changes.

Comment: Changing the read-only flag will allow you to save the file using your SSIS tool, but TFS will not pickup the change until you manually checkout/checkin after you make your changes (causing read-only to be turned on again).  That's why I said this approach is not recommended.  I'll update my answer with a screenshot of turning on Local Workspaces which is what you should do.